# (Excel) Check if date in cell > todays date by 30 days, AND another cell = "Open" Then colour cell Red

Tags: excel, date, formula

Anybody know the formula for: `Check if date in cell > todays date by 30 days, AND another cell = "Open" Then colour cell Red`

Basically have 2 cells. One with text in it which says "Open".
and a Last updated cell with a date in it, lets say 05/01/2020.

I need to add conditional formatting to basically highlight 05/01/2020 cell if the computers local date is 30 days + the date in the cell Only if the first cell says "Open" and the date cell is > 30 days compared to local date.

This is what I have so far

(Conditional formatting)

```
If cell value less than = today()-30    #Highlights in chosen colour as red
```

The above works if the cell is > 30 days but it's the AND statement im having trouble with.

Below is the Psuedo version of what i'm looking for

> IF A1="OPEN" and B2 is more than 30 days old by comparing to local
>   machine date then highlight B2 in red

See link for cells in question
[Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQG3f.png)

Comment: `=AND(Cell1="Open",TODAY()-cell2>30)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use the following formula, replacing `cell1` and `cell2` with references to the actual cells:

```
=AND(cell1="Open",TODAY()-cell2>30)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, implemented this formula with no success unfortunately

Comment: Can you edit your question with the cells in question and maybe a sample screenshot?

Comment: Thanks! couldn't  of been more clearer than that , problem solved!